# How to check mulitple files empty or not in php?

Tags: php

I want to check multiple files name are empty or not in php before inserting the database.

Kindly check what I am doing:

Try 1:

```
   $filename1 = $_FILES['photo1']['name'];
   $filename2 = $_FILES['photo2']['name'];
   $filename3 = $_FILES['photo3']['name'];


   if (empty($filename1 == "" && $filename2 == "" && $filename3 == "")) 
   {  
    $errors[] = 'All Images are required.';


   }else{
   // Files are not empty
   }
```

Try 2:

```
  if (empty($_FILES)) {  
     $errors[] = 'All images are required.';
     }else{
     }
     if (empty(['photo1']['name'];)) {  
     $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 1.';
     }
     if (empty(['photo2']['name'];)) {  
     $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 2.';
     }
     if (empty(['photo3']['name'];)) {  
     $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 3.';
     }
```

For me both are not working as I want,

1)if someone upload image 1 then no error will show.

2)if someone do not upload image 3 then error will show kindly upload image 3

3)If someone do not upload image 2 then error will show kindly upload image 2

4)If someone do not upload all images then error will show all images are required.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function correctly. It doesn't support multiple parameters and you have to recall it for every var you need to check.

```
if (empty($filename1) && empty($filename2) && empty($filename3))
{
```

btw, I think what you need in this case is the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function, determining if a variable is set and is not NULL. This time, it support multiple parameters.

```
if (!isset($filename1, $filename2, $filename3))
{
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried if (isset($filename1, $filename2, $filename3))
{
  $errors[] = 'All images are required.';

} but it also not showing the error message.

Comment: My bad, you need to negate your condition, check edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The time to check for empty or missing values is before you assign to a variable. Trying to assign, for example, `$filename1 = $_FILES['photo1']['name']` will result in an undefined index notice, if photo 1 hasn't been uploaded. The following code sets each variable to the appropriate filename, or `null` if it hasn't been uploaded. Then you can check for each one in turn.

```
<?php
$filename1 = $_FILES['photo1']['name'] ?? null;
$filename2 = $_FILES['photo2']['name'] ?? null;
$filename3 = $_FILES['photo3']['name'] ?? null;

if ($filename1 && $filename2 && $filename3) {
    // do stuff
} elseif (!$filename1 && !$filename2 && !$filename3) {
    $errors[] = 'All images are required.';
} else {
    if (!$filename1) {
        $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 1.';
    }
    if (!$filename2) {
        $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 2.';
    }
    if (!$filename3) {
        $errors[] = 'Kindly Upload Image 3.';
    }
}
```